# Why can't I select my radio buttons in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm mapping through my data and creating a table. On each table row, there is a radio button. I want to be able to select that button, which will give me all the data from the row, however, I'm not even able to select it. It doesn't work. What am I doing wrong here?

I've tried adding a value, an onChange listener, and the checked property, but it looks like I'm doing something wrong. I know you need all of those but I'm not sure exactly what I'm doing wrong.

```
export default class ResultTable extends Component {
    state = {
        data: [
            {
                insightName: 'Name 1',
                description: 'name 1 desc',
                created: new Date(),
                createdBy: 'Person 1',
                category: 'insight 1',
                status: 'published'
            },
            {
                insightName: 'Name 2',
                description: 'name 2 desc',
                created: new Date(),
                createdBy: 'Person 2',
                category: 'insight 2',
                status: 'published'
            },
            {
                insightName: 'Name 3',
                description: 'name 3 desc',
                created: new Date(),
                createdBy: 'Person 3',
                category: 'insight 3',
                status: 'published'
            }
        ],
        selectedRow: ''
    }

    handleRadioButton = (e) => {
        e.persist()
        console.log('clicked', e)

         this.setState({
             selectedRow: e.target.value
         }, () => console.log(this.state.selectedRow))
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Table striped bordered hover>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th> </th>
                            <th>Insight Name</th>
                            <th>Insight Description</th>
                            <th>Created</th>
                            <th>Created By</th>
                            <th>Category</th>
                            <th>Status</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        {
                            this.state.data.map((obj, idx) => {
                                return (
                                    <tr onClick={this.selectRow}>
                                        <td>
                                            <div class="Form-group">
                                                <div class="Form-radio Form-radio--inline">
                                                    <input id="radio7" name="radioInline" type="radio" value={obj.insightName} checked={this.state.selectedRow === obj.insightName} onChange={this.handleRadioButton} />
                                                    <label for="radio7"></label>
                                                </div>
                                                <div />
                                            </div>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>{obj.insightName}</td>
                                        <td>{obj.description}</td>
                                        <td>{obj.created.toString()}</td>
                                        <td>{obj.createdBy}</td>
                                        <td>{obj.category}</td>
                                        <td>{obj.status}</td>
                                    </tr>)
                            })
                        }
                    </tbody>
                </Table>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: looks like it works fine: https://codepen.io/bozdoz/pen/jONvBMM?editors=0010

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The solution below will work:**
[Sandbox with working solution](https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-rubin-2q8lc)

> Pay attention that JSX is not equal HTML, so when using:
>   class should be className
>   onclick should be click
>   onchange should be change

**Also your mistake was this part, the below is the right way to use it:**

```
checked={state.selectedRow === obj.insightName ? "checked" : null }



import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

function App() {
  const state = {
    data: [
      {
        insightName: "Name 1",
        description: "name 1 desc",
        created: new Date(),
        createdBy: "Person 1",
        category: "insight 1",
        status: "published"
      },
      {
        insightName: "Name 2",
        description: "name 2 desc",
        created: new Date(),
        createdBy: "Person 2",
        category: "insight 2",
        status: "published"
      },
      {
        insightName: "Name 3",
        description: "name 3 desc",
        created: new Date(),
        createdBy: "Person 3",
        category: "insight 3",
        status: "published"
      }
    ],
    selectedRow: ""
  };

  const handleRadioButton = e => {
    e.persist();
    console.log("clicked", e);

    this.setState(
      {
        selectedRow: e.target.value
      },
      () => console.log(this.state.selectedRow)
    );
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <table clasName="striped bordered hover">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th> </th>
            <th>Insight Name</th>
            <th>Insight Description</th>
            <th>Created</th>
            <th>Created By</th>
            <th>Category</th>
            <th>Status</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {state.data.map((obj, idx) => {
            return (
              <tr click={state.selectedRow}>
                <td>
                  <div className="Form-group">
                    <div className="Form-radio Form-radio--inline">
                      <input
                        id={`radio${idx}`}
                        name="radioInline"
                        type="radio"
                        value={obj.insightName}
                        checked={
                          state.selectedRow === obj.insightName
                            ? "checked"
                            : null
                        }
                        change={handleRadioButton}
                      />
                      <label for="radio7" />
                    </div>
                    <div />
                  </div>
                </td>
                <td>{obj.insightName}</td>
                <td>{obj.description}</td>
                <td>{obj.created.toString()}</td>
                <td>{obj.createdBy}</td>
                <td>{obj.category}</td>
                <td>{obj.status}</td>
              </tr>
            );
          })}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Comment: You are misleading. React uses `camelCase`, `onClick` & `onChange` are correct.

Comment: When I changed the "change" to "onChange", this answer worked for me! Thank you. I just don't understand why I have to use the ternary operator for the "checked" attribute and why I couldn't do it like I had it before....

Comment: @AnnahI usually to mark as selected the html code is: checked='checked'  and not checked=true, so this is the reason :)

Answer (score 0):

I think it is working good. I've tested your code. Have a look.
https://codesandbox.io/s/modest-roentgen-ymcu8

If you're having the issue then you can try to remove the `e.persist()`. There is the possibility that it is blocking your code to set the new State.